# How do I forward a rvalue reference?

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

If I have a std::vector-wrapper, do I forward it to my underlying vector as:

```
void vector_wrapper::emplace_back(value_type&& val) { 
  wrapped_vector_.emplace_back(std::move(val)); 
}
```

or

```
void vector_wrapper::emplace_back(value_type&& val) {
  wrapped_vector_.emplace_back(val); 
}
```

?

Comment: A named rvalue reference is an lvalue, so use `std::move`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351669/rvalue-reference-why-arent-rvalues-implicitly-moved) question could be helpful. Also I suggest change your `emplace_back` to accept variable number of arguments(like in the `vector`), since element may be constructed with more than one argument.

Comment: Xeo: Could you make an answer of that so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `value_type` is a deduced template parameter, use `std::forward<value_type>(val)` (from the `<utility>` header); this is part of the *perfect forwarding* recipe.  If not, and `value_type` is a specific type (including a non-deduced template parameter), use `std::move(val)` (also from `<utility>`).  If you take **soon**'s advice and make `emplace_back()` take a variable number of arguments, that will (most likely) mean using a variadic template and perfect forwarding, which means `forward<T>` would be the appropriate construct.

Examples:

Perfect forwarding:

```
template<typename... P>
void vector_wrapper::emplace_back( P &&...p ) {
    wrapped_vector_.emplace_back( std::forward<P>(p)... );
}
```

Specific or non-deduced type for `value_type`:

```
void vector_wrapper::emplace_back( value_type &&val ) {
    wrapped_vector_.emplace_back( std::move(val) );
}
    // Note: emplace_back() idiomatically uses perfect forwarding,
    // so the first example would typically be more appropriate.
    // This second form is more applicable to push_back()
```

(Technically, you can use `std::forward<>()` for both cases, since it is equivalent to `std::move()` for non-lvalue-reference types, and is therefore a fancier way of writing `std::move()`.  But it is more concise to say `std::move()` when the type-introspection of `forward<>` isn't needed, and more significantly, it better communicates the intent of the code.)