# Why do we need to explicitly call std::move on a reference rvalue function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

One thing has been bugging me for quite a while now. When passing a reference rvalue to a function parameter, I need to forward it explicitly when passing it to another function, otherwise the reference rvalue is lost.

```cpp
void foo(const string&);
void foo(string&&);

void bar1(string&& x) { foo(std::move(x)); } // Calls foo(string&&)
void bar2(string&& x) { foo(std::forward<string>(x)); } // Calls foo(string&&)
void bar3(string&& x) { foo(x); } // Calls foo(const string&), why not foo(string&&)?
```

[» Sample program «](http://ideone.com/9fVq2b)

I have no doubt about how and why `bar1` and `bar2` work.

What bugs me in `bar3` is that its parameter is of type `string&&`, so when I call `foo(x)` I would expect the compiler to set a higher priority for a function with a signature that matches exactly the parameter, i.e. `foo(string&&)` instead of `foo(const string&)`.

I’ve read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078582/why-exactly-is-stdmove-needed-on-a-function-parameter-which-is-already-an-rval) (which really looks like my problem) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351669/rvalue-reference-why-arent-rvalues-implicitly-moved) (which is supposed to be a duplicate, except it’s not) but the answers weren’t very helpful.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just remember this simple rule:  If an object has a name, it is an lvalue.  Doesn't matter how you got it, if it has a name it is an lvalue.

Comment: ^^ this, plus inside the function `x` is a name, thats basically the reason you need forwarding